# How to display?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, pug

I am fetching data from mongodb using mongoose below code shows the output on web browser.

```
app.get('/users', function (req, res) {

    User.find({}, function (err, docs) {

    res.json(docs);

});

});
```

I need to display this data in HTML format in index.jade inside a table.
How to do? please help

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell express where your view files are and that you are using jade.

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```

Then render the index file with the user data.

```
app.get('/users', function(req, res, next) {
  User.find({}, function (err, docs) {
    res.render('index', { users: docs });
  }
});
```

Now inside the index.jade you create a table and iterate over the users.

```
table    
  each user in users
    tr
      td
        user.name
```

Something along those lines.

Check expresses and jades documentation.

http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.render

http://jade-lang.com/reference/iteration/

*edit - I'm assuming your just using express and jade here and not looking to render the json on the front end with a front end framework.